how to fetch a streaming response using vercal ai sdk with langchain?
I am new to vercal ai sdk and I am trying to create a simple chatbot using vercal ai sdk in next js with langchain framework. I folowed the tutorial given on official docs but still unable to fetch any data after sending request to server
I tried folowing typescript code in file app/page.tsx
'use client';

import { useChat } from 'ai/react';

import { Message } from "ai";
const initialMessages: Message[] = [
  {
    role: "assistant",
    id: "0",
    content:
      "Hi! I am your chat assistant",
  },
];

export default function Chat() {
  const { messages, input, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useChat({initialMessages});
  console.log("The output data is =====",messages);
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-md py-24 flex flex-col stretch">
      {messages.length > 0
        ? messages.map(m => (
            <div key={m.id} className="whitespace-pre-wrap">
              {m.role === 'user' ? 'User: ' : 'AI: '}
              {m.content}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="fixed w-full max-w-md bottom-0 border border-gray-300 rounded mb-8 shadow-xl p-2"
          value={input}
          style={{color:"black"}}
          placeholder="Say something..."
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

and file app/api/chat/route.ts code is
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { Message as VercelChatMessage, StreamingTextResponse } from 'ai';
import { ChatGoogleGenerativeAI } from "@langchain/google-genai";
import { BytesOutputParser } from '@langchain/core/output_parsers';
import { PromptTemplate } from '@langchain/core/prompts';

 

 
const TEMPLATE = `You are a story teller that writes every answer as story in three paragraphs
 
Current conversation:
{chat_history}
 
User: {input}
AI:`;
 

export async function POST(req:NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const messages = body.messages ?? [];
  const formattedPreviousMessages = messages.slice(0, -1).map(formatMessage);
  const currentMessageContent = messages[messages.length - 1].content;
 
  const prompt = PromptTemplate.fromTemplate(TEMPLATE);
  
  const model = new ChatGoogleGenerativeAI({ model: "gemini-pro"});

 
  const outputParser = new BytesOutputParser();
 

  const chain = prompt.pipe(model).pipe(outputParser);
  const stream = await chain.stream({
    chat_history: formattedPreviousMessages.join('\n'),
    input: currentMessageContent,
  });
 
  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}

I expect message array of object in page.tsx to contain three objects {initial message, my question, response from llm} after i enter the question but it remain two as no response from server returned and added to message array.
Furthermore I am using correct key as llm works perfectly if i use any invoke statement in route.ts and print it on console but it does not return anything to page.tsx
